# Passing my class data to a driver class gives exception?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have this class that gives me the RGB values of the Color Object.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ColorChooserRGB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create new HashMap
        HashMap<String, Object> colorObjectsHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Fill with colors
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("black", Color.BLACK);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("lightGray", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("blue", Color.BLUE);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("magenta", Color.MAGENTA);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("cyan", Color.CYAN);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("orange", Color.ORANGE);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("darkGray", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("pink", Color.PINK);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("gray", Color.GRAY);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("red", Color.RED);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("green", Color.GREEN);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("white", Color.WHITE);
        colorObjectsHashMap.put("yellow", Color.YELLOW);

        // Get all values from the HashMap and display them.
        System.out.println("Values of colorObjectsHashMap: ");
        Collection<Object> objValues = colorObjectsHashMap.values();
        for (Object value : objValues) {
            System.out.println("\t" + value);
        }
    }    

    public Color getColor(String selected) {
        return Color.decode(selected);
    }

    public Collection<Object> getKeySet() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Values of colorObjectsHashMap:      
java.awt.Color[r=192,g=192,b=192]   
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=255]     
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=175,b=175]   
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]       
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]     
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=0]     
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=255]     
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=0]     
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]   
java.awt.Color[r=128,g=128,b=128]   
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]   
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]   
java.awt.Color[r=64,g=64,b=64]
```

FLOW: I need to use my new class RGB data in the ColorTest class to select a color and draw a shape in that color. HOW do I pass my Object data to this ColorTest class when it calls my class at "chooser = new ColorChooser();"??? I changed my main to "public Object[] colorChooser(List list)" and added "return objValues.toArray();", but that's not it. So what do I return? I've tried several of the suggestions from my IDE but it always cascades in to more problems. Thanks for any assistance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class ColorTest extends JFrame {
    private JList<String> colorList;
    private ColorChooser chooser;
    private JPanel drawPanel;

    public ColorTest() {
        super("List Test");

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        chooser = new ColorChooser();

        // create a list with items in colorNames array
        colorList = new JList<String>(chooser.getKeySet().toArray(new String[0]));
        colorList.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        colorList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        // do not allow multiple selections
        colorList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JPanel choosePanel = new JPanel();

        // add a JScrollPane containing JList to content pane
        choosePanel.add(new JScrollPane(colorList));

        // set up event handler
        colorList.addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() { // anonymous inner class
                    // handle list selection events
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
        ); // end call to addListSelectionListener

        drawPanel = new JPanel(); // create a drawing panel
        drawPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // add the panels to the window
        add(drawPanel);
        add(choosePanel);

        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        // obtain the selected value
        Object selected = colorList.getSelectedValue();

        // set the color
        g.setColor(chooser.getColor((String)selected));

        // draw the rectangle
        Rectangle bounds = drawPanel.getVisibleRect();
        g.fillRect(bounds.x + 10, bounds.y + 30, bounds.width - 15, bounds.height - 15);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColorTest application = new ColorTest();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
} // end class ColorTest
```

RESULT:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

---

UPDATED ColorChooser:
ColorChooser line 38 = return Color.decode(objValues);
ColorTest line 62 = g.setColor(chooser.getColor((String)selected));
RESULT:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:1161)
    at java.awt.Color.decode(Color.java:729)
    at edu.austincc.colors.ColorChooser.getColor(ColorChooser.java:38)
    at edu.austincc.colors.ColorTest.paint(ColorTest.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:842)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace of exception?

Comment: Is that what this is?: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at edu.austincc.colors.ColorTest.<init>(ColorTest.java:22)
 at edu.austincc.colors.ColorTest.main(ColorTest.java:70)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Comment: Yes. However, it is difficult to derive line numbers from the example provided. Can you tell us what is there on lines 22 and 70 of `ColorTest.java`?

Comment: Sure, and thanks for your patience! 
line 22 ... colorList = new JList<String>(chooser.getKeySet().toArray(new String[0]));
line 70 ... ColorTest application = new ColorTest();

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace posted in comments, below line seems to be throwing an Exception:

`colorList = new JList<String>(chooser.getKeySet().toArray(new String[0]));`

`chooser.getKeySet()` is returning a `null` object and hence, calling `toArray` on a null object throws an exception. Below is the implementation of `getKeySet()`:

```
public Collection<Object> getKeySet() {
    return null;
}
```

In ideal sceario, what it should return depends on functionality of the class/module. However, if we want to prevent the exception then we can use the following implementation (It just returns an empty list btw):

```
public Collection<Object> getKeySet() {
    return Collections.<Object>emptyList();
}
```

Comment: Ah haa, I see. So that produces the color box thing without the colors; so I just need to figure out how to get my colorObjectsHashMap.values() in to the return of the getKeySet()?

Comment: Still having trouble with passing the values; Can you tell what the problem is from this?:  

From ColorTest there is a problem with "g.setColor(chooser.getColor((String)selected));"                                  when it tries to access ColorChooser ...
    public Color getColor(String objValues) {
            // g.setColor(chooser.getColor((String)selected))
            return Color.decode(objValues);
    }

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you update example in question? It is difficult to understand the code from comments.

Comment: Absolutely, I listed code from the problem lines and the full stacktrace under UPDATED: